# UE4.23 - Cast of child of GameUserSettings fails

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I've derived GameUserSettings to add a bunch of custom properties to it. I tried making accessible in blueprint by creating a static method that returns the current GameUserSettings cast to my Child Class.

```
 Custom_Settings * Custom_Settings::GetCustom_Settings() {
     return Cast<Custom_Settings>(GEngine->GameUserSettings);
 }
```

Unforunately, the cast fails and returns null, which leads to UE complaining about trying to access none in blueprint (naturally). There was a similar question here, but that led me nowhere, since I've already set DefaultEngine.ini to use my custom settings

```
 [/Script/Engine.Engine]
 GameUserSettingsClassName=/Script/MyGame.Custom_Settings
```

I've checked whether GEngine can fetch the Settings, and it appears it can. Does anybody have an idea why the cast might be failing?

Comment: Well UE4 is known to not pick up things from the *.ini files. You can try to subclass the GEngine class - this one is known yo work and make it work with you Custom_Settings class

Comment: Just for convinience please show how you declare your custom class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all manner of things, deleting the .vs, Binaries, Intermediate, Saved and .sln, rebuilding the VS Files and building the project from there turned out to solve this problem.